# Obj-C - Filter returned data in tableview for first values in dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view that pulls data from my database, and displays it in my tableview cells. The values returned are:

```
 This is the messages data (
        {
        body = "13-10-2017 12:12";
        name = "Leeya";
    },
        {
        body = "09-10-2017 19:37";
        name = Leeya;
    },
        {
        body = "test";
        name = "Jessica";

    }
```

That said, when my dictionary comes back with multiple arrays containing the same 'name' value (as it is in this case, 'Leeya'), I only want my tableview to display the first of these arrays (one cell), much like in a chat app when you see a list of conversations.

The code I have currently accomplishes this, but it literally only returns ONE cell and ONE array, populated by the most recently posted data. E.g. tableview returns cell:

```
LEEYA
```

When it should return:

```
LEEYA
JESSICA
```

See my code below. I assume this is because the line

> NSString *nodeTitle = self.messages[0][@"name"];

is always equal to one username, and thus it returns one value.

**So my question is:** How can I make that line function so that, "If 'name' value in dictionary self.messages appears more than once, only show the first value" ? **Or in other words:** **If 'name' value is equal to 'name' in arrays that follow, only show the first?**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        NSString *nodeTitle = self.messages[0][@"name"];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", nodeTitle];
        NSArray *filteredArray = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        id firstFoundObject = nil;
        firstFoundObject =  filteredArray.count > 0 ? filteredArray.firstObject : nil;
        NSDictionary *firstObjects = firstFoundObject;
        NSLog(@"The first objects are %@", firstObjects);
        static NSString *PointsTableIdentifier = @"MyMessagesCell";

        MyMessagesCell *cell = (MyMessagesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PointsTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyMessagesCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


        }
```

I hope I explained this clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest not trying to do this in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Instead, when you first get your data from the server, write a method that takes the input array and filters it to remove duplicates. Something like this:

```
- (NSArray *) UniqueEntriesForArray: (NSArray *) sourceArray {
  NSMutableArray *results  = [NSMutableArray array];
  NSMutableSet *uniqueStrings = [NSMutableSet new];
  for (NSDictionary *element in sourceArray) {
    NSString *name = element[@"name"];
    if (![uniqueStrings contains: name]) {
       [uniqueStrings addObject: name];
       [results addObject: element];
    }
  }
  return [results copy];
}
```

(My Objective-C is getting a little rusty so that might need some adjustment. It would also be cleaner if you used the new typed array syntax for Objective-C, but I don't remember that off the top of my head.)

Comment: Something like `NSMutableArray<NSDictionary*> *results` and `NSMutableSet<NSString*> *uniqueStrings`

Comment: I'm not sure where in your above code I would insert my own values? E.g. the data in my code is self.messages, and it's a dictionary?

Comment: Basically you're trying to filter your `messages` array in a method where you just have to return a cell populated with data. So, it's better to filter data in advance in order to have a cleaner `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Add this method to your view controller, then after you retrieved data, do something like : `NSArray *filteredMessages = [self UniqueEntriesForArray:self.messages` and store this filteredMessages on another property. Then, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you'll just have to do : `NSDictionary *cellData = self.filteredMessages[indexPath.row]` and populate your cell with this dictionary.

Comment: @McNight This makes sense, however when I paste the method above into my viewcontroller, XCode screams at me, stating "Use of undeclared identifier 'element', and "No visible interface for NSMutableSet declares the selector 'append:'. Where does 'element' come from? And why is 'append:' not a selector in the above?

Comment: @Brittany I edited his answer. Please wait a bit (it's not `append` but `addObject` and it's `for (NSDictionary *element in sourceArray)`

Comment: @Brittany My code is *in review*. Here is a link to the modified answer : https://gist.github.com/McNight/9b88e488836eb6a89cbc9ac8123b2a59

Comment: @McNight You are, a genius. Lol. Thank you so much. It works. I have one last question: How do I store filteredMessages on another property? Sorry for my newbness (it's prob super easy and the syntax is prob just confusing me, but I appreciate your help!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156789/discussion-between-mcnight-and-brittany).

Comment: McNight, thanks for the edits. I'm rusty enough in Objective-C that I really need to compile and test the code or I'm going to get stuff wrong. :(